# Issue adding featured image option to functions.php

Tags: php

I'm creating my own theme and I'm looking to add a featured image option by adding:

```
add_theme_support( $feature, $arguments );
```

Into the `functions.php` file. When I do this I get this error:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /wp-content/themes/Precise/functions.php:3) in /wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1228
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you doing this inside the [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) hook?

Comment: No, I literally added the above code to my blank functions.php file. Please could you provide an example of the init loop?

Answer (score 1):

As user [/u/majick](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/76440/majick) suggests in the comments below: the better option may be [`after_setup_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) which looks like this:

```
function theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );
```

---

Another options is to use `init`.

```
function theme_init() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'theme_init' );
```

The [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) hook explicitly states:

> Fires after WordPress has finished loading **but before any headers are sent**.

Comment: maybe `after_setup_theme` would be a better option?

Comment: @majick Good point!

Comment: Now i'm getting this:

    function theme_init() { // Get your theme options and loop through them etc. add_theme_support( $feature, $arguments ); } add_action( 'init', 'theme_init' );
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/danieljoseph/preciseinvestments.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Precise/functions.php:5) in /home/danieljoseph/preciseinvestments.co.uk/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1228

Comment: @DannyBoy Well, what's on line 5 of your `functions.php` file? I just ran the above code without issue.

Comment: add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );

Comment: I'm literally just adding the above code to a blank function.php file. Should I be adding anything else/wrapping it in anything else?

Comment: @DannyBoy Do you have a opening PHP tag? If it's empty then it should look *exactly* like [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SuNfdjjW)

Comment: Yeah, still getting this:

function theme_setup() { // Get your theme options and loop through them etc. add_theme_support( $feature, $arguments ); } add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/danieljoseph/preciseinvestments.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Precise/functions.php:5) in /home/danieljoseph/preciseinvestments.co.uk/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1228

Comment: This is line 1228 of the pluggable.php file : header("Location: $location", true, $status);

Comment: @DannyBoy Difficult to say. If your `functions.php` looks like the linked pastebin above then the issue may lie elsewhere. Maybe disable all plugins and try running the function in the default theme to see if you run into the same issue.

Comment: From the above warning what I see, the whole PHP code is printed. I suspect  PHP tag is closed somewhere. Make sure you have your code in between PHP opening/closing tags! e.g. `<?php //code here ?>`

Answer (score -1):

ok I changed line 1228 in the pluggable.php file from:

```
header("Location: $location", true, $status);
```

To:

```
header("Location: $location", false, $status);
```

And it's done the trick. I now have the 'Featured Image' option in the screen options.

Comment: Do **NOT** edit core files - it is bad and when updating the problem will reoccur, because the core files get updated.

Comment: Do you have a better solution you could post for me?

Comment: Is there a way to override this in the functions.php file?

Comment: What about Howdy McGee's answer?

Comment: It didn't seem to work. Probably something i'm doing wrong. Will give it another go.

Comment: If you are using Howdy McGee's suggestion, which is correct, at least it is how I do it, and it isn't working, my guess would be, you have some other issue.